# Word and symbol for putting two sets in to a larger set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

After doing some work with sigma-algebra, I'm stunned that I can't recall ever seeing any name or notation for this. However, consulting Google and Wikipedia has turned up nothing. What I'm looking for is quite simple, I want to find a name and symbol (I'll use $\cdot$ for now) for whatever set operation would give results such as $\{1\} \cdot \{2\} = \{\{1\}, \{2\}\}$. Obviously, I would like to make some appeal to the idea of a collection of sets, but I've never seen any terminology such as "{A, B} is the collection of the two sets A and B".

Comment: There's no symbol. The operation is called "pairing".

Comment: @AsafKaragila As in the axiom of pairing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_pairing)? That seems sensible, but how would it be said "{A,B} is the pairing of A and B"?

Comment: The pair of A and B.

Comment: The complexity of a given concept and the need for a dedicated notation (beyond the very basic building blocks) is inversely proportional. That's why we don't have a need for your $\cdot$, since we can just write $\{a,b\}$ for $a \cdot b$ and that why we have an established notation for much more complex concepts like constructing the generic extension of $M$ by $g$ (written $M[g]$). This isn't a defect -- it's a feature. Overloading your text with notation is incredibly frustrating for your reader. If you don't believe me, I'm happy to show you some torturous examples ;-)